# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Db' not found in prestashop

Tags: php, ajax, module, controller, prestashop

Sorry for my english.

I am a beginner in `prestashop` and I am still trying to learn more about it.

### I created a module (`/module3`) in /modules directory. This has next files:

-`module3.php` (the main php file of this module)
-`/views/templates/hook/module3.tpl` (the template for `module3.php`)
-`/controllers/front/products.php` (the controller of this module)
-`/views/templates/front/products.tpl` (the template for my controller)
-and also `/controllers/front/take_product.php` (which will be called by `products.tpl` by `ajax`).

### My `/views/templates/front/products.tpl` has next ajax:

```
`   function print_product (id_product) {
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('id_product', id_product);

        take(function(rezultat) {
            $("#product_div").html(rezultat);
        });

        function take(rezultat) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1/prestashop/modules/module3/controllers/front/take_product.php",
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
            }).done(function(output) {
                rezultat(output);
            });
        }
    }`
```

### My `/controllers/front/take_product.php` has next code:

```
`
    @ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ps_product WHERE id_product="'.(int)$_POST["id_product"].'"';
    $result = Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
    echo $result;
`
```

### That's what `/views/templates/front/products.tpl` receives and prints:

```
`
Fatal error: Uncaught Error:
 Class 'Db' not found in 
/var/www/html/prestashop/modules/module3/controllers/front/take_product.php:6
 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
/var/www/html/prestashop/modules/module3/controllers/front/take_product.php 
on line 6
`
```

### Maybe you think I need a class-controller in `/controllers/front/take_product.php`. 
That's why I also changed my `/controllers/front/take_product.php` with next code:

```
`
    @ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

    class Module3take_productsModuleFrontController extends 
    ModuleFrontController
    {
        public function initContent()
        {
            parent::initContent();

            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ps_product WHERE id_product="'.(int)$_POST["id_product"].'"';
            $result = Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
            echo $result;
        }
    }
`
```

### But now `/views/templates/front/products.tpl` receives and prints another error:

```
`
Fatal error: 
Class 'ModuleFrontController' not found in 
/var/www/html/prestashop/modules/module3/controllers/front/take_product.php 
on line 6
`
```

### So... Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the take_product.php directly in your ajax.
Instead of hard coding the url, use the Link object in your tpl:

```
url: "{$link->getModuleLink('Module3', 'take_products', [], true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}",
```

This way, it will have the correct url to load the Prestashop and use the modulecontroller.

Just a reminder of another solution, but not so correct. You don't need it to extend the ModuleFrontController (as you tried before), just to "load" prestashop using in the beggining of the file:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) .'/../../../../config/config.inc.php');
```

cron_currency_rates.php uses this instead of being a controller. But, again, this is not the best way. Just wanted to point out the difference.

Comment: I modified the url (from products.tpl) in: "{$link->getModuleLink('Module3', 'take_product', [], true)}" and I let the controller (take_product.php) how it was. But now I have another error in console: POST [lonk](http://127.0.0.1/prestashop/index.php?fc=module&amp;module=Module3&amp;controller=take_product&amp;id_lang=1 404) (Not Found)

Comment: Change the your controller name to Module3Take_productModuleFrontController, (you have plural in you class). And delete the cache/class_index.php

Comment: I put your url and I let the take_product.php as class-controller. No, the error is the same like mine from introduction: Fatal error: Class 'ModuleFrontController' not found in /var/www/html/prestashop/modules/module3/controllers/front/take_product.php on line 5

Comment: My class starts like that: class Module3take_productModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController

Comment: Not sure it will solve, but usually it needs the |escape:'html':'UTF-8' when creating the link. I've updated above.

Comment: If I put your url, the ajax doesn't go in take_product.php because it appears an error in console: an 404 (not found). But if I keep my url, the ajax go in take_product.php and returns on page this error: Fatal error: Class 'ModuleFrontController' not found in /var/www/html/prestashop/modules/module3/controllers/front/take_product.php on line 5. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: updated again. you have two options. your initial try, with no class and no controller, but add the `require_once( _PS_ROOT_DIR_ .'/settings/config.inc.php');` to load the prestashop. the other option is to use the controller. If it gives the 404 error, have add the |escape:'html':'UTF-8'? if you did, there could be an error/typo somewhere. you can also go to Preferences > SEO & URLs and click add new page to set a custom url.

Comment: I did also what you said (no class and no controller) using require_once( _PS_ROOT_DIR_ .'/settings/config.inc.php'); and now the error is: Notice: Use of undefined constant _PS_ROOT_DIR_ - assumed '_PS_ROOT_DIR_' in /var/www/html/prestashop/modules/module3/controllers/front/take_product.php on line 5

Warning: require_once(_PS_ROOT_DIR_/settings/config.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/prestashop/modules/module3/controllers/front/take_product.php on line 5

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's not defined at the moment. It should be `require_once( dirname(__FILE__) .'/../../../../settings/config.inc.php');`

Comment: config folder not settings

Comment: thanks for the correction. btw, the modulefrontcontroller option should have worked, maybe the _ was "interfering" (never used it in a modulefrontcontroller) or some other reason I could figure out.